# How do I add assembly references in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code, project, assembly-references

So I've come across a similar issue twice now while working on my first project in C#.  When trying to add either `using System.Data;` or `using System.Timers;`, I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'x' doesn't exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?).

I have tried beginning a new project and running `restore` to see if I had accidentally removed something in the dependencies, but upon generating a new project I still receive the same error.  I have tried to research the question and have seen answers referring to the 'solutions explorer', but as far as I can see there doesn't seem to be such a feature by this name in Visual Studio Code 1.8.

**Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to get these working, perhaps by manually adding into the dependencies?**

Comment: Are you sure you're not finding help/advice relating to Visual Studio (not VS Code)? Solution Explorer is a feature in VS but I'm not sure it exists in VSC.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That sounds quite plausible, I wasn't really clear on the difference.  I'll try searching again with a focus on the VSC aspect.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever OK, it looks like you're right regarding the absence of Solution Explorer.  It seems I'd have to add missing references to the dependencies file manually, but as to where or how I'd know what version number to add, I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675162/install-a-nuget-package-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 89, accepted):

## .csproj Project file

The following topic applies to ***`.csproj`*** project file and : .NET Core 1.x SDK, .NET Core 2.x SDK

Adds a package reference to a project file.

```
dotnet add package
```

### Example

Add `Newtonsoft.Json` NuGet package to a project:

```
dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json
```

## .json Project file

The following topic applies to ***`.json`*** project file:

This guide walks you through the process of adding any assembly reference in Visual Studio Code. In this example, we are adding the assembly reference ***System.Data.SqlClient*** into .NET Core C# console application.

***Note***

- *At step #6, enter the assembly reference that you want.*
- *Some assembly reference is applicable to .NET Framework and it will gives you error(s).*
- *OleDb is not available in .NET Core, probably because it's not cross platform.*

**Prerequisites**

1. Install [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download)
2. Install [.NET Core SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) (Preview 2 version)
3. Install [NuGet Package Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jmrog.vscode-nuget-package-manager) from the Visual Studio Code Extension Marketplace
4. Install [C# extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp) from Visual Studio Code Extension Marketplace

**Steps**

1. Launch Visual Studio Code
2. Open your project folder
3. Launch VS Code Command Palette by pressing ***F1*** or ***Ctrl+Shift+P*** or ***Menu Bar > View > Command Palette***

[image]

4. In ***Command Palette*** box, type ***nu***

[image]

5. Click on ***NuGet Package Manager: Add Package***
6. Enter package filter e.g. ***system.data*** (*Enter your assembly reference here*)

[image]

7. Press Enter
8. Click on ***System.Data.SqlClient***

[image]

9. The following prompt pops up

[image]

10. Click on ***Restore***

[image]

11. The following ***Output panel*** pops up

[image]

12. In the ***Explorer panel***, click on ***project.json*** to open it

[image]

13. In the ***Editor panel***, it shows the assembly reference added into ***project.json*** file

[image]

14. Assembly reference, ***System.Data.SqlClient*** used in ***Program.cs***

[image]

Comment: there is no suggestion with Nuget , do we need to install something else for that ?

Comment: @Saurabh Yes, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jmrog.vscode-nuget-package-manager

Comment: There is no Nuget: Install/Reference command, only Add Package!

Comment: what about System.Data.OleDb? no suggestion for that in command palette.

Comment: @EmonHaque: OleDb is not available in .NET Core, probably because it's not cross platform.

Answer (score 9):

Use the command `dotnet add package` to add a package reference to your project. For example: `dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json`, which adds the package reference to the `*.csproj` project file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="9.0.1" />
```

and now you can run the command `dotnet restore` to restores the dependencies of your project.

Reference: [dotnet add package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-package)

Answer (score 2):

drag the dll file and drop it into the bin folder

[image: drag the dll file and drop it into the bin folder]

Answer (score 2):

Above answer from ikolim doesnt work as indicated by someone else too, there is no, Nuget: Install/Reference command. There is only Add Package! So the answer in the below link solved my problem. Manually editing the Myproject.csproj file.

[Duplicate of this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381064/vscode-c-sharp-add-reference-to-custom-assembly)

Answer (score 2):

I've stored the files in a project folder named "dlls" and added the reference files in my .csproj file like this:

> ```
>  <ItemGroup>
>      <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Client.Policy.Portable">
>       <HintPath>dlls\Microsoft.Office.Client.Policy.Portable.dll</HintPath>
>     </Reference>
>     <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Client.TranslationServices.Portable">    
>  <HintPath>dlls\Microsoft.Office.Client.TranslationServices.Portable.dll</HintPath>
>     </Reference>
> </ItemGroup>
> ```

Comment: This works well on VS Code 1.67 in 2022. Having a third party refs folder is much better than dropping files into your Debug folder, which surely should be output only (& not checked into source control). Note the use of "Reference", not "PackageReference", the latter being for nuget refs only. Best answer!

Answer (score -2):

In case of extisting .dll reference,
Right click project
Add existing item > select path to .dll
After added dll in project,right click .dll

> build-action = Content, Copy-to-output-dir = Always/ or if newer

Comment: vs code not visual studio