# VSCode C# Issue Adding An Assembly Reference

Tags: c#, reference, visual-studio-code, nuget, nuget-package

I have the C# VSC extension as well as the NuGet Package Manager installed. Here is my VSC version info:

[image]

First, I create a brand new console application in VSC with the command:

> dotnet new console

This gives me the code:

```
using System;

namespace ReferenceTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

I now want to create a `using System.Windows.Forms;` reference. When I start typing this using statement however, intelli-sense fails me:

[image]

I found [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000798/how-to-add-assembly-references-in-visual-studio-code) already but in step #5 the autofill option shown is not there:
[image]

When I try to improvise and follow other instructions I've found in my searching by using the

> NuGet Package Manager: Add Package

option, I cannot select System.Windows.Forms
[image]

I have looked for a `project.json` file per the instructions of several sites but I can only find a `project.assets.json` file and it doesn't look very similar to what I see in the examples I find. This issue is not only for `System.Windows.Forms` but other references I try as well.

Comment: I don't think VSC is capable of building WinForm applications; you need [Visual Studio Express](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-express/).

Answer (score 0):

Windows Forms and WPF applications are not supported in .NET Core, only in .NET Framework.

have a look at the following article:

https://stackify.com/net-core-vs-net-framework/