# How do I reference an assembly (Entity Framework System.Net) using c# using visual studio code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

At 5h40m47s of this tutorial he shows the viewer how to create and reference an assembly.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPeGkedZykA&t=20696s
This link is a decent tutorial on how to learn c#
My main problem is that I am learning on visual studio code and some things that he does are more complicated on visual studio code.
How do I do that in visual studio code (simply)?

Hope this helps with being more specific: he adds a System.Net reference from the Entity Framework library.
So How do I add the reference to the EntityFramework System.Net from my main simple program?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add assembly references in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000798/how-to-add-assembly-references-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Harry, be sure to read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - This question is very broad and doesn't provide any useful information for someone to help answer your question.

Comment: I wondered this, I appreciate your thoughts, can you recommend where this would be better placed or maybe I can edit it.

Comment: the main thing is :
creating a reference to an assembly, I have found several solutions which are confusing for me and hoped there would be a simpler solution to answer this problem, he gets the .netframework assembly and creates a reference to it in part of the tutorial, I try to do this but it is really not clear how to do that for me using visual studio code and I guess this does not really help you either, if you watched that section of the video and then tried to do the same thing in visual studio code how would you do that?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50782758/2565026

Comment: Some of you suggested an answer <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000798/how-to-add-assembly-references-in-visual-studio-code> but when trying to implement that , I got a circular error.

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805204/adding-reference-to-another-project-from-visual-studio-code/50782758#50782758> seems to be useful but the guy in the youtube advert is adding the stuff from the Entity Framework library System.Net to the console program he is using. So I am still confused

Comment: so I found this which might be part of what he says from the microsoft entity framework.... what do you guys think?

Comment: so I found this which might be part of what he says from the microsoft entity framework.... what do you guys think? 

<https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/install/> typed "Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" in the terminal, then

Comment: ok so far here is what I think I have:

Terminal:
I typed :
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Install overall was successful, warnings saying my csproj was using it so I then deleted the .csproj file,
Then typed: dotnet new console --force
included in the cs file: using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; saved it, and after I typed dotnet build in the terminal which was successful. in the  cs file using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Net;     Have I created the reference to the System.Net now from the entity Framework??

Comment: I also have pressed F1 , then typed in NuGet package manager then add package, then I typed EntityFramework, then I did install, then after it needed restoring, i restored that, which could be another method of adding the package I guess

Comment: Thanks only just seen this