# How can I enable IntelliSense for external C# code in VS Code without creating a new project or moving files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, intellisense, csproj

I have a main Assembly-CSharp.csproj and associated files that provide functions, definitions and documentation for them (and thus hints/tooltips/auto-completion/etc.). And I have another folder outside of that project open in VSCode, but when I create scripts in this outside folder I can't access any definitions from the main project. How can I reference them without moving any files between folders if I only want IntelliSense to work?

I tried googling it, official docs [suggest setting up entire new project](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/project-management) but as far as I could understand you need the main csproj inside the workspace, so that doesn't work for me.

Comment: How are you planning to access the functions of the aforementioned Assembly-CSharp.csproj project? I'd suggest you setting that up first in order to gain IntelliSense

Comment: I'm asking because I don't know how it works and if it's even possible. I only assumed it's possible based on my experience coding in python, where IntelliSense could load relevant definitions and documentations by simply adding import statement. So I assumed there could be a similar solution with C#

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805204/adding-reference-to-another-project-from-visual-studio-code