# CS0246 error with OdbcConnection line in C#

Tags: c#, odbc

Ive been chasing this CS0246 error for a couple hours and am not sure how to resolve it. Given this simple C# code:

```
using System;
// using Microsoft.Data.Odbc; 
using System.Data.Odbc; 

namespace dotnetdb
{
    class Program
    {
        static private void SelectRows(string[] args)
        {
            string passWord = "PWD=password";
            string uName    = "UID=username";
            string dbServer = "SERVER=server";
            string dbName   = "DATABASE=db";
            string driver   = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}"
            string connString = // assembled from above 

            string sql = // sql;

            OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connString);

            conn.Open();

            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn);

            // work with cmd

            Console.WriteLine("Didnt kick the bucket!");
        }
    }
}
```

The `Microsoft` stanza on line 2 yields a `CS0234` error. The stanza on line 3 (from the Microsoft docs) gives me the CS0246:

`Program.cs(20,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OdbcConnection' could not be found`

I use this ODBC connection in go and python all the time but this is my first attempt at using it with C#. Also my first ever C# program. The code above is scraped almost directly from the MS docs - what am I missing? How do I get access to `System.Data.Odbc`?

Am I trying to run before I learn how to walk with C#?

Note that applications created with `dotnet build [console|webapi]` build and run just fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it included as a reference?

Comment: Maybe read the rest of the error message... the part you didn't post. "Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: yes that's my "walk before I run" point - I don't understand what "(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" is telling me? Doing this in VSCode, not in Studio. Do I need to add it to one of the project files?

Comment: Going from C# to Sql Server, why on earth would you use Odbc rather than the native SqlClient?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the server/application needs to run on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add it as a reference. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000798/how-to-add-assembly-references-in-visual-studio-code) on how to add a reference in Visual Studio Code. I also noticed that your program doesn't have a `Main()` and that'll prevent it from compiling also.

Change this:

```
static private void SelectRows(string[] args)
```

to

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

Or call it from `Main()` like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SelectRows(args);
}

private static void SelectRows(String[] args)
{
    ...
}
```

In general references are a piece of compiled code, mostly in `.DLL` format which you can include in your own project so you can use the methods/code that the reference provides.

For example,

Let's say I have `MyMath.dll` which was created by somebody and I want to use this method in it.

```
int Add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

I have to include that `MyMath.dll` that somebody else created in order to use that `Add()` method. So when I want to use it, I use something like this.

```
using MyMath; // MyMath.dll

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyMath calculator = new MyMath();
    int result = calculator.Add(1, 2);
}
```

If you don't know, Visual Studio has a [free community version](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) that's pretty powerful too.

Comment: thanks this is almost certainly the answer though, as usual, it won't work for me here at my desk since VSCode is unable to get a local issuer cert... I will try again from home and mark as an answer there once I get it working. You are correct about `Main()` of course - I forgot to change it back (it is set that way by `dotnet new console`) before posting here.

Comment: With some futzing around I was able to add the relevant package at the CLI with 

`dotnet add package System.Data.Odbc -v 4.5.0-preview2-26406-04` 
 and it builds and runs fine - thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to NuGet - I will get it working at home this weekend. I have been up and down the same corporate cert tree with `npm`, `pip` and `go get`...