# Trying to add System.Media namespace to a Visual Studio Code Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-assembly

I am currently working on a small game-project with the goal to make a program using CSharp.

The project is a console app that has a text-based menu and starting screen and my current goal is to add audio playing as the app launches.

I have researched what I need in order to get music to play but I lack the assembly to do so.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Media;

namespace AntFightingSim
{
class Program
{
    public static string[] menuButtons = new string[] { " Fight!(Press Space) ", " Exit The Game!(Press Escape)" };
    public static bool appRunning = true;
    public static string path;
    public static int buttonCount = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        path = "C:/Users/Spyros/OneDrive - Södertörn university/Project Folder/Csharp Projects/RandomProjects/AntFightingSim/Resources/Dragon Ball FighterZ - OST - Loading Theme.wav";
        MenuMethod();
    }

    static void MenuMethod()
    {

        while (appRunning && buttonCount != 1)
        {
            SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
            player.SoundLocation = path;
            player.Load();
            player.PlayLooping();
            Console.WriteLine("ANT INVESTMENT SIMULATOR");

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start");
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.ReadKey(true);

            Console.Write(menuButtons[0]);
            Console.Write(menuButtons[1]);
            ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
                StartGame();
            else if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {

                buttonCount++;

            }

        }
        while (appRunning && buttonCount == 1)
        {
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Are you sure about that?(Press Escape Again)");
            ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                appRunning = false;
            }

        }

    }


    static void StartGame()
    {
        buttonCount = 1;
    }
}

static class Ant
{
    public static int strength;
    public static int dexterity;
    public static int agility;
    public static string name;
    public static bool gender;
}
}
```

I googled the error:

> The type or namespace name 'Media' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\Spyros\OneDrive -
>   Södertörn university\Project Folder\Csharp Projects\RandomProjects\AntFightingSim\AntFightingSim.csproj]

but I don't have the slightest clue as to how to get said assembly reference into Visual Studio Code. So far, Google has only given me 2004-2015 results for Visual Studio only.

Which leads me here. For the first time, I wrote and posted a question in StackOverflow out of desperation. Is there a way to add said namespace/different namespace or is it just not possible in Visual Studio Code? God Speed.

Edit:

After a bit of searching, i have figured out that the `System.Media` namespace and its assembly (PresentationCore.dll) does not exist within the NuGet list.

Since i lack the knowledge of a proper assembly that helps me with my goal, i am now at the point where i need to ask for an altenative to `System.Media` and its ability to play audio files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the assembly containing System.Media. A detailed guide can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42399545/1621861

Comment: I checked that post as i was writing this post and have done most of the steps needed. It just that the specifc namespace that i am looking for does not exist (PresentationCore.dll)  . Do you know any altenatives?

Answer (score 0):

In case your environment is .NET core you would like to build application in .NET Framework.

Comment: That would be the idea, yes. Currently i am just running tests on my console project by using `dotnet run`.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/784) may this help you. its my first day here. I might be wrong