# Visual Studio Code extensions

Tags: vscode-extensions, hana

Hope someone can help me, is there an SAP Hana extension for Visual Studio Code?

I'm used to Visual Studio where you just reference and bingo.
Regards,
Will

Answer (score 0):

All,
Found the solution at the following link.
[How to add assembly references in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000798/how-to-add-assembly-references-in-visual-studio-code/42399545)
It is done via packages.
Thanks,
Will