# How to add system.servicemodal package in asp.net core vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

i'm new to .NET core and trying to consume WCF service.Generated the proxy class using svcutil in Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/Bin when i use the generated proxy class and config and tried to run using dotnet run getting error as

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Order' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'MessageContractAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ServiceModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IsWrapped' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'OperationContractAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ServiceModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Tried to add System.ServiceModel.Primitives in vscode but no luck getting error

```
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'System.ServiceModel.Primitives (>= 4.5.3)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'
```

Tried below steps

[How to add assembly references in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000798/how-to-add-assembly-references-in-visual-studio-code/42399545)

i can't find the system.serviceModal assembly

anyone assist to fix these issue

Comment: did you fix this?