# C# - Add assembly reference in VSCode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

How can I add an assembly reference to my project without using Visual Studio? I don't exactly know what an assembly reference is, but I'm being told I'm missing one and answers to my problem tend to start with "Right click here in Visual Studio...".

Code:

```cs
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: You are using the wrong project type.  Start a new project and select Window Form project.

Comment: When you go to create a windows form project you should use the "dotnet new winforms" command to create a winforms project. Which is where I am assuming you went wrong. If you just want to know how to add refferences in vscode try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000798/how-do-i-add-assembly-references-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: Why not use Visual Studio though? It was created specifically for developing C# (and other .NET/C++) applications. You'll have a much easier time using it than you will trying to make programs in VSCode.

Comment: @Jesse Multiple reasons: I don't have much space on my pc, and VS wouldn't help with that. Two, I like the idea of having one IDE for all languages. C# is the first language I have used in VSCode that is lacking support. Java, Python, C++, HTML / CSS / JS all work great in VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to create a windows form project you should use the "dotnet new winforms" command to create a winforms project. Which is where I am assuming you went wrong. If you just want to know how to add refferences in vscode try [How do I add assembly references in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000798/how-do-i-add-assembly-references-in-visual-studio-code).